# How to create calendar view in IOS 5.1?

Tags: ios5, view, calendar

How can I create a calendar view in IOS 5.1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into using the third-party calendar component [Kal](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal), which "aims to provide an open-source implementation of the month view in Apple's mobile calendar app".  Sounds like that might fit what you are looking for.  The [Read Me](https://github.com/klazuka/Kal) page contains example usage and instructions to integrate the component into your project.